# Laravel 5.1 can't find template using @yield

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a problem using @yield from one view to another. I couldn't get anything from my question.blade.php file, even if using just a simple text.

My create.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layout/layoutAdmin')


@section('content')  
<div class="container">
  <h1>Add a new inventory</h1>

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/menu/inventories/', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7 {!! $errors->has('text') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
  {!! Form::label('text', 'Name:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('text', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  {!! $errors->first('text', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7">
  {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
  @yield('content2')
</div>
</div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

And my question.blade.php file:

```
@extends('inventory.create')

@section('content2')


 <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7">
      {!! Form::label('type', 'Type:') !!}
      {!! Form::number('type', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>    
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7 {!! $errors->has('introduction') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
  {!! Form::label('introduction', 'Introductory Text:') !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('introduction', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  {!! $errors->first('introduction', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7">
  {!! Form::label('value', 'Values:') !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('value', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7 {!! $errors->has('language') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
  {!! Form::label('language', 'Language:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('language', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  {!! $errors->first('language', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-7">
    {!! Form::label('is_active', 'Active:') !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('is_active', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>


@stop
```

My QuestionController:

```
 public function create()
    {
        return view('inventory.question');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('admin/menu/inventories/new/question', 'QuestionController@create');
```

Edit: fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

You are yielding to a section called `container2` and you have placed your content in a section called `content2`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It was a typo when I re-wrote the code to stackoverflow. I changed the @yield('container2') to @yield('content2') and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @randomuser33 Try replacing `@stop` with `@endsection`.  Are you getting an error page, or what is the result of the code you posted?